# How to implicitly cast all arguments of a template function to the highest resolution type?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

In a project I'm working on I have a templated function similar to this where all of the arguments should be of type T

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> bool aWithinBOfC(T a, T b, T c)
{
    return std::abs(a - c) < b;
}
```

the issue I'm having is it won't compile if all of the arguments are not of the same type but it seems reasonable that it should implicitly cast similar types to the one with the highest resolution before evaluation. Is there any way to get a call like this to be valid?

```
int main()
{
    double a{1.2};
    double b{1.4};
    float c{0.1f};

    std::cout << aWithinBOfC(a, b, c) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. You want the compiler to do an implicit **conversion**.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template<typename T>
bool aWithinBOfCImpl(T a, T b, T c) {
  /* actual implemenattion */
}

template <typename ... Args>
auto aWithinBOfC(Args... args) {
  return aWithinBOfCImpl<std::common_type_t<Args...>>(args...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pvsKjz)

Comment: It's cool to see it can be done but I think I'll just use a template with multiple types to keep things clean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need implicit conversions at the call site. The compiler will implicitly convert the types to the largest one in the expression in the return statement.

```
template <class T, class U, class V>
bool aWithinBOfC(T a, U b, V c) {
    return std::abs(a - c) < b;
}
```

Comment: This was my initial thought but I wondered if there was a cleaner way to do it with only one template type but as I can see from Igor's answer it seems to only get more convoluted.  Thanks